# Logic behind Cardano master key generation from mnemonic

Tags: ed25519

Could anyone clarify the logic  behind Cardano master key generation from mnemonic.

There is a specification BIP32-Ed25519 https://github.com/LedgerHQ/orakolo/blob/master/papers/Ed25519_BIP%20Final.pdf

But it seems that Cardano doesn't use that algorithm https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses/blob/e3ce58addfeefccc16db888008d57fa9a732464d/core/lib/Cardano/Address/Style/Shelley.hs#L1047-L1060

Answer (score 3):

The seed phrase is generated in cardano-addresses, briefly explained [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses/blob/4a369086471d0849d40ba384ca39a4ab94f23d82/core/lib/Cardano/Mnemonic.hs#L124-L149). This is then used as entropy for private key generation, the logic for this is in [cardano-crypto package](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-crypto/blob/ce8f1934e4b6252084710975bd9bbc0a4648ece4/src/Cardano/Crypto/Wallet.hs#L119-L133)